# using the Find() function with an array of objects and then using the result props (JSX)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

the main situation is the next one: I want to use the current url as the param in order to find and use the props of that object. My issue... I wondering if this is the suppose method I should use, I willing to heard your ideas.

'''

```
class Lista extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();

        this.state = {
            servicios : [{
                servicio : 'Comerciales',
                video : '',
                descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
                link : '/servicios/comerciales',
                id : 0
            },
            {
                servicio : 'Eventos',
                video : '',
                descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
                link : '/servicios/eventos',
                id : 1
            },
            {
                servicio : 'Branding',
                video : '',
                descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
                link : '/servicios/branding',
                id : 2
            },
            {
                servicio : 'Tecnicos',
                video : '',
                descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
                link : '/servicios/tecnicos',
                id : 3
            },
            {
                servicio : 'Operacion con Dron',
                video : '',
                descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
                link : '/servicios/operacion-con-dron',
                id : 4
            }
            ]
        }
    }

    render(props) {
            return (
                this.state.servicios.find((lista => lista.link == props.match.url) => (
                    <Servicio/>
                ))
            )
    }
    
}
```

'''

As expected the code itself is actually incomplete, and even I could made it showing the whole list but for some reason I now completely stuck with this problem. I will update if I achieve progress. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find a matching service object if one exists.

You could [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) the service object and pass it as props to the `Servicio` component if there's a match. And you have to access the props in a class component via `this.props`.

```
render() {
  const service = this.state.servicios.find(
    service => service.link === this.props.match.url
  )
  if (service) {
    return <Servicio {...service} /> // this will pass `servicio`, `video`, `link`, `desscription`, and `id` as props
  }

  return <p>Not Found</p> // or whatever you want to return
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the easy explanation. It completely solve my issue, and how to correctly use the function inside of an object.

Kind regards mate

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map` method to iterate the array and use `if` condition to check `props.match.url` matches with link key in each object and return `<Servicio/>`

```
class Lista extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
      super();

      this.state = {
          servicios : [{
              servicio : 'Comerciales',
              video : '',
              descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
              link : '/servicios/comerciales',
              id : 0
          },
          {
              servicio : 'Eventos',
              video : '',
              descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
              link : '/servicios/eventos',
              id : 1
          },
          {
              servicio : 'Branding',
              video : '',
              descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
              link : '/servicios/branding',
              id : 2
          },
          {
              servicio : 'Tecnicos',
              video : '',
              descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
              link : '/servicios/tecnicos',
              id : 3
          },
          {
              servicio : 'Operacion con Dron',
              video : '',
              descripcion : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, aliquid nulla harum illo eius cumque esse error similique molestiae molestias non eligendi! Ex laboriosam consequatur laborum recusandae aut ullam velit.',
              link : '/servicios/operacion-con-dron',
              id : 4
          }
          ]
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>{this.state.servicios.map(lista =>{
          if(lista.link == this.props.match.url) {
            return (<Servicio/>);
        }})
        }
        </>
  )
  
}
}
```

Comment: The `render` method in a class component does not receive props as an argument and you have to access it via `this.props`. And you don't need to use `map` since the service objects have different `link`s and only one service object can match with `this.props.match.url` in a given render.